# TypeScript not evaluating boolean left operand for && operation

Tags: typescript

I'm using TypeScript, and I had something similar to the below code snippet:

```
const getString = (string: string) => string

// No errors
getString("foo"); 

// Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)
getString(false && "foo"); 

// No errors
getString(1 > 2 && "foo");
```

I was surprised to see that no error was thrown for `getString(1 > 2 && "foo")`, since `1 > 2` evaluates to false, a boolean value that `getString()` doesn't accept. Why is it that TypeScript didn't evaluate `1 > 2` and throw an error?

Comment: Generally, Typescript is not going to try to mathematically prove whether a particular Boolean expression is always true, always false, or possibly either. The literal types `true` and `false` are for *literals*, and I don't see any value in having Typescript infer literal types for non-literal Boolean expressions where it would be simpler for the programmer to write a literal if they wanted a constant Boolean value. The real question is why an expression like `boolean && string` is assignable to type `string` when the first operand isn't a literal `true`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable [strictNullChecks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) - then, it'll produce the error as expected.

[image]

For some strange reason, without that option, TypeScript determines the type of the argument to be `'' | "foo"` - otherwise, it'll be `boolean | "foo"`.

```
const aBool = 1 > 2;
const res = aBool && "foo";
```

results in `res` being automatically determined to be the type of `const res: "" | "foo"`. This seems like something that should be a bug, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain in more detail, why, precisely, null checks need to be enabled in order to generate a type error for an expression that can never be `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag When strictNullChecks is false, null and undefined are effectively ignored by the language. This can lead to unexpected errors at runtime. I believe it was made for easy migration from JS to TS

Comment: It *works*, but I don't quite understand it either. `false` is not null nor undefined.

Comment: @captain-yossarian: That does not explain anything whatsoever, since there are no `null`s or `undefined`s in this code.

Comment: @JörgWMittag my bad. I believe without this flag, TS uses lazy evaluation and don't check whether `1<2` is `false` or `true` it just infers it to `boolean`. Btw, it has been  added in TS 2.0 https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html